# React Native Android Release No Image

Tags: react-native

I am trying generate APK Release version as shown in documentation. Release APK was build SUCCESSFUL but there are NO static images. Any ideas how to love this?

Comment: what image type, dimensions ? Is worked on developmen? You should add some code snippets.

Comment: I have already soled this. Thank you. I used this react-native bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/ --entry-file ./index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --platform android --dev false

Comment: @Mag you should add your comment as answer, I had resolved by problem by using same command, and it seems that it had reduced my app size by 3-4MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
react-native bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/ --entry-file ./index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --platform android --dev false
```

Then

```
adb install app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have a permission in android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

as it may be caused by that device is unable to connect to the web.

Comment: when images from web works fine, there are no Static images, from folder.

Comment: This soled my issue react-native bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/ --entry-file ./index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --platform android --dev false